# Zend_Db_Table_Exception: A table must have a primary key, but none was found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I want to insert data in a table using zend framework . I have following table structure

[image]

When I try to insert data in this table I found error

```
 Zend_Db_Table_Exception: A table must have a primary key, but none was found
```

When i specify `protected $_primary ='id'` in my table I found error

```
Primary key column(s) (id) are not columns in this table ()
```

I have deleted the table and created from scratch but all is vain. I have been trying to solve this problem since hours but haven't got any solution.

My model looks like

```
protected $_name = "affiliate_specialities_banners";
//protected $_primary = 'id';
protected $_adapter = null;

public function init() {
    $this->_adapter = $this->getAdapter();
}

public function addData($data) {
    try {

        $id = $this->insert($data);
    } catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {

        die($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $id;
}
```

Please any suggestions......

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess you're using the table metadata cache, and so ZF is using an older version of the table structure that doesn't include the primary key. Removing the cache files should fix this. Alternatively, make absolutely sure it's connecting to the database you're looking at in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Well I am working on a already developed system. I tried to find out where cache is being stored but unable to find. :-( I have deleted all tmp folder inside www directory but nothing happened. :-(

Comment: Search the source for `setDefaultMetadataCache`, that might help you find if and where the cache is being used